# Fragment activity communication by passing Context object to onAttach()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Im trying to implement fragment to activity communication.

Went through [android developer](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) doc where an Activity object is passed to onAttach life cycle and set up the Fragment-Activity communication.

This [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)) asks to pass Context object instead of Activity. I replaced all the Activity objects by Context objects in the life cycle method onAttach. But it is throwing a NullPointerException while calling the method of the interface from Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        colourChangerInterface = (ColourChangerInterface) context;
    }
    catch (Exception exp){
        System.out.println("error!");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please give a small example of the usage in the new way ?
Thanks

**Edit** :

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077086/android-onattachcontext-not-called-for-api-23) link where detail discussion is there on the same issue.
The issue is because of the broken API 'onAttach()'; it doesn't get called at all when Context object is passed.

A simple and quick solution found from the above link is to move the code from onAttach to onCreate.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new master/detail Activity using android-studio app-wizzard? that should contain every thing you need.

Comment: No, Im extending AppCompatActivity. Let me explore about master/detail activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example that will describe you the communication between `Activity` and `Fragment`. Suppose you have a Interface `ICommunication`. This is given below:

```
public interface ICommunication {
    public void testMethod();
}
```

Now you have a `Activity` name `MainActivity` that implements `ICommunication` then it must have implements the method `testMethod()`. This method will like this:

```
@Override
    public void testMethod() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It's called from Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now, suppose this `MainActivity` belongs a `Fragment` name `TestFragment` . If you want to access `testMethod()` of MainActivity from `TestFragment` then you can simply call using this way :

```
((ICommunication)getActivity()).testMethod();
```

Here , `TestFragment` must be hold on `MainActivity`.

My related answer with source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36468506/3073945)
Thats it :)