# How I can pass two parameters from a fragment to an activity

Tags: android

Hello how can I pass two parameters from a fragment to an activity? I tried to do this but I can't.
 I got only the ref in the TextView editRef but the TextView et_login is empty

```
public class ResultFragmentC  extends Fragment implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, container, false);
        et_login = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.et_login);
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        String log = intent.getStringExtra("login");
        et_login.setText(log);
......

}
......

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ViewResult.class);
            HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String tid = map.get("ref");
            intent.putExtra("ref", tid);
            String tid2 = map.get("log");
            intent.putExtra("log", tid2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

ViewResult.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_result);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        String ref2 = intent.getStringExtra("ref");
        et_login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_login);
        String log = intent.getStringExtra("log");
        et_login.setText(log);
        editRef = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editRef);
        editRef.setText(ref2);
}
```

Comment: This should work, are you sure log is not empty or null when you put it in?

Comment: check my this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36467198/3073945

Comment: @cricket_007 it's two. i'm sorry

Comment: @cyroxis yes it's not empty

Comment: I have a login form. so I want to display the login in all the fragments and activities. In the first fragment I have a listview with the login but when I click in the listview the login wasn't displayed in the activity

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check you are using the *same keys* for the intents.

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
String log = intent.getStringExtra("login");
```

Is not the same as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String log = intent.getStringExtra("log");
```

What you've shown in `ViewResult.java` should work with what you have in `onItemClick` assuming `map.get()` isn't returning you `null`.

It should be mentioned though, that using the Activity intent is not how you give parameters to Fragments. Please see [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment).

Comment: I have a login form. so I want to display the login in all the fragments and activities. In the first fragment I have a listview with the login but when I click in the listview the login wasn't displayed in the activity

Comment: Well, like I said, `ViewResult.java` should work and display the data unless you ended up putting null in with `intent.putExtra("log", tid2);`

Comment: Also, are `fragment_result.xml` and `view_result.xml` practically the same thing? They both have a `@+id/et_login`?