# Getting nullpointer when hide androic activity control form fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i want to hide my layout which is in activity class and its visibilty handle in fragmetn class below is my code

Myfragment.java

```
Tags.mStringVarientSoldOut="yes";
ActivityDetailTest site = new ActivityDetailTest();
site.isSoldOut();
```

ActivityDetailTest.java

`mLinearLayoutBottom` is already declared in my `onCreate()` method of activity class

```
public void isSoldOut()
{


    if (Tags.mStringVarientSoldOut.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    {
        mLinearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        mLinearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

when I run above code i m getting nullpointer error at line             **mLinearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);**
any idea how can i solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: mLinearLayoutBottom is defined in activity class so how can you call it in fragment ? where are you getting reference of it in fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

If `mLinearLayoutBottom` is declared in `ActivityDetailTest` with public visibility  then use  it as in Fragment :

```
ActivityDetailTest objActivity = (ActivityDetailTest) getActivity();
objActivity.mLinearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K: yes working!!

Comment: Rly bad practice. You shouldn't change activity's field from outside.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect way of activity and fragment communication via Interface.

You should declare a interface and implement it in your activity. Then from your fragment you can send command via that interface.

Here is code example, Your interface is:

```
public interface IActivityController{
void hideOrVisibleView(boolean action);
}
```

Now, implement this interface in your activity. After implementing this interface, your activity code will like this:

```
@Override
public void hideOrVisibleView(boolean isHide) {

    if(isHide){
      mLinearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
      }else{
        mLinearLayoutBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
       }
}
```

Now, in your fragment based on your code logic just use this line to hide/visible your View in activity.

```
((IActivityController)getActivity()).hideOrVisibleView(true/false);
```

here, if you send true, view will hide and if false then view will visible.

I think, this will the best solution. Hope this will help you.

My related answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36832079/3073945) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36467198/3073945)

Comment: Your answer is also working

Comment: Thanks, brother.
If you think, this is the best solution then mark it as best answer :) .

Answer (score 0):

Without interface you can also handle by this way

pass Linearlayout object in fragment class constructor from your activity class

```
MyFragment mMyframge=new MyFragment(mlinearLayoutBottom);
```

**MyFragment.java**

create constructor

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public MyFragment (LinearLayout mLinearLayout){
    this.mLinearLayout=mLinearLayout;
}
```

and now handle your condition in fragment class

```
if (Tags.mStringVarientSoldOut.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
{
    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else
{
    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Harshal Kalavadiya : ya working!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But here has some problem:
To pass value via Constructor in fragment, it will show error message when generate release APK. If there has another efficient way to do this things, why you pass a View to another class?

Comment: Md. Sajedul Karim: i also release APK with same code in my other project and in my case it is working fine