# How to communicate from Mainactivity to Fragment using callback interface?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I'm having navigation drawer with four menu's and each menu has own fragments
, Inside first fragment has view pager sliding tab with 2 fragments,

Activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

////////////// Here I'm replacing each fragments ////////////////
        <FrameLayout   
            android:id="@+id/main_content_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ManinActivity- DrawerSelection

```
 public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentClass = Home_Tab_Fragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_myorders:
                fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_myoffers:
                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notification:
                fragmentClass = FourthFragment.class;
                break;

        }

                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_content_framelayout, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

}
```

HomeTabFragment

```
public class Home_Tab_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewpager, container, false);
          viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SlidingTabAdapter adapter = new SlidingTabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstTabFragment(), "First TAB");
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondTabFragment(), "Second Tab");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

SlidingTabAdapter

```
public class SlidingTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public SlidingTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

layout_viewpager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

FirstFragment

```
public class FirstTabFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Foodies");
        return rootView ;
    }

  public void updateFirstFragmentValues(){
      //Doing some operations
  }

}
```

**Inside MainActivity , I want to call FirstTabFragment method [updateFirstFragmentValues()]**

I tried adding TAG in FirstTabFragment ,

```
public static final String TAG ="FirstTabFragment.TAG";
```

Then I invoked in MainActivity like below , but Fragment always null.

```
 public void invokeMethodFromFirstTabFragment() {
        FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FirstTabFragment fb=(FirstTabFragment)fm.findFragmentByTag(FirstTabFragment.TAG);
        if (null != fb) {
            fb.updateFirstFragmentValues();
        }else{
            L.m("Fragment is null===========");
        }
    }
```

Kindly advise , How to call "FirstTabFragment" method from inside "MainActivity"

> Please note FirstTabFragment is not added directly to MainActivity ,
>   its added through "Home_Tab_Fragment".

Comment: Have you considered using something like a callback for that?

Comment: @Georgy Savatkov : I'm using callback interface for communicating fragment to activity , but this case I want to communicate from activity to fragment. Can you provide sample code for this ?

Comment: If **FirstTabFragment is not added directly to MainActivity**. You can not use interface callbacks for this type of requirement..!

Comment: @Janki gadhiya , Kindly advise any possible way to call fragment public method from MainActivity . my real scenario is I want to refresh fragment recyclerview adapter data once data loaded from server.

Comment: I think your layout design have bit more confusion.Reply me i will try to give solution

Answer (score 1):

Alright, reading all of the responses of yours, I get that you just simply need to pass data to a fragment upon creation and be able to execute some of Fragment's methods. Ok, simple enough:

### IMessageFragment interface

```
public interface IMessageFragment {
  /**
   * Method to receive new message text
   * @param text Message text to receive
   */
   void updateMessageText(String text);
}
```

### MessageFragment

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment implements IMessageFragment {
  /**
   * Bind views using ButterKnife
   */
  @BindView(R.id.textView) TextView mTextView;

  /**
   * Bundle data
   */
  private String mMessageText;

  /**
   * Unique id of bundle data
   */
  private static final String MESSAGE_EXTRA_KEY = "f_message";

  /**
   * New fragment pattern. This is pretty much all the magic PLUS this
   * looks by far better than `new Fragment()` upon instatiation
   */
  public static MessageFragment newFragment(String message) {
      // 1. Create new fragment
      MessageFragment auctionFragment = new MessageFragment();
      // 2. Create bundle for fragment params
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      // 3. Put position
      args.putString(MESSAGE_EXTRA_KEY, message);
      // 4. Set arguments
      auctionFragment.setArguments(args);
      return auctionFragment;
  }


  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_fragment, container, false);

      /**
       * Bind views
       */
      ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

      // Update UI
      updateUI();

      return view;
  }

  /**
   * Method to update value of mTextView
   */
  private void updateUI() {
      if(!mMessageText.equals("")) {
          mTextView.setText(mMessageText);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void updateMessageText(String text) {
      mMessageText = text;
      updateUI();
  }
}
```

Stuff is pretty simple and the interface exists only for good code style and to support design patterns.

Comment: can you please add some code for, how to send text through IMessageFragment from Mainactivity to  MessageFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You cannot directly access `FirstTabFragment` method from your MainActivity. Firstly you have to call `Home_Tab_Fragment` method from activity. Then from that method you can call `FirstTabFragment` method.

Here is strategy:

Step 1:  `Home_Tab_Fragment` to `FirstTabFragment` communication

define an interface like this

```
public interface IHomeToFirstFragmentController{
          void firstFragmentMethod();
    }
```

Now implements the `IHomeToFirstFragmentController` in your `FirstTabFragment`. then you have to implements the `firstFragmentMethod()`.

```
@overrride
    void firstFragmentMethod(){

    }
```

Call this `firstFragmentMethod` method from  `Home_Tab_Fragment` using this way

```
YOUR_fragmentInstance.firstFragmentMethod();
```

**Step 2:**  Activity to `Home_Tab_Fragment`:

define an interface like this

```
public interface IActivityToHomeTabController{
          void callFirstFragment();
    }
```

Now implements the `IFragmentController` in your `Home_Tab_Fragment`. then you have to implements the `callFirstFragment()`.

```
@overrride
void callFirstFragment(){
  YOUR_fragmentInstance.firstFragmentMethod();
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Call fragment using this way

```
((IFragmentController)YOUR_fragmentInstance).firstFragmentMethod();
```

Hope this will give you an idea about this topics. For more info visit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36832079/3073945)

Comment: @Sajedul Karim , I tried your approach but unable to call IFragmentController in Mainactivity
`IFragmentController mHomeTabCall;
mHomeTabCall=(HomeTabCall) MainActivity.this;
mHomeTabCall.callFirstFragment();`
Error:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.activities.IFragmentController`

Comment: sorry, that was my mistakes. I edited my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score -1):

First for all, you create interface :

```
public interface CallBackListener{
      void onCallBack();
}
```

In Fragment

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment{
    private CallBackListener mCallBack;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        AppCompatActivity activity;
        if (context instanceof AppCompatActivity) {
            activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
            try {
                mCallBack= (CallBackListener ) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " class must be implement" +
                        " OnBackFragmentListener");
            }
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
}
```

Use :

```
mCallBack.onCallBack();
```

And in Activity, you must implements interface :

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBackListener{

   @Override
   public void onCallBack(){
   // Do somethings here...
   }
}
```

Comment: @lrish Louis , Please note I dont want call from fragment to activity. I want to call from Activity to fragment . , How to attach interface in Activity class

Comment: I'm sorry. I think if you want pass data from activity to fragment, you can use argument of fragment, broadcast receiver, handler - message...

Comment: You can't use interface to callback from activity to fragment (personal opinion)

Comment: @lrish Louis , I can't get fragment instance in  MainActivity because fragment is not directly connected with MainActivity , its attached in ViewPager Host fragment , and that host fragment called in MainActivity . Any idea to solve this case ?